# JavaFX getting scene from a controller

Tags: java, javafx-2, keylistener, scenebuilder

I recently started playing around with Java FX, FXML, and scene builder, and I've been trying to add key listeners to one of the controllers for a scene. When I do this though, the key listeners don't work as they should, and I figure it's because they're not focused onto that particular scene. I tried to get access to the scene the controller was part of in order to set it directly, but it comes up that it's part of a null scene.

Is there a way to gain access to the scene that this controller is used in in order to try and assign key event and listeners to that particular scene? Should I go through the rootController which is static throughout the whole application? Or, better yet, is there a simpler way of going about this?

Most examples I see assume that everything is mostly together in a main class or separated amongst a couple of other classes without FXML being brought in, and I'm not sure how to apply their fixes when I have the java controllers, FXML pages, and the main application all separated.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use any of the controls that is bound in the Controller and use [`getScene()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#getScene--) on it.

Remember **not to use it in [`initialize()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/Initializable.html#initialize-java.net.URL-java.util.ResourceBundle-)** as the root element(though completely processed) is still not placed on the scene when `initialize()` is called for the controller

```
public class WindowMainController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Button button;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println(button.getScene()); // Gives you the Scene
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        System.out.println(button.getScene()); // Prints null
    }

}
```

Comment: Yup! That gives me the scene instead of null ^^. I was trying to get it while in the init() method, so that must have been the problem! Thank you! Now, I can hopefully get the keylisteners to work :D

Comment: If you are trying to add `keylisteners` to scene, I would advice to do it where the scene is created. *Though I am not sure of your requirement*

Comment: I'm trying to make a game using all of this stuff, and the way I have it now there's one scene that would be the root, and I just switch the stage depending on where the user would be at each time. Would I just add it onto the scene when I change the stage, so the key events are already there?  And how would I access elements inside the new controller and stage from outside the controller?(i.e. making a keyevent to move an image when the image is instantiated in the stage controller)

Comment: I hope with `switch the stage`, you mean `switch the view`. `Would I just add it onto the scene when I change the stage, so the key events are already there`, you can do it, if there is not something stopping you from doing it. `And how would I access elements inside the new controller and stage from outside the controller?` you can use a property binding for this

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar problem where I wanted to get the scene whenever the scene is loaded and not on a button click. So I used the following approach.

```
public class WindowMainController implements Initializable {
  @FXML
  private AnchorPane parentPane;

  @Override
  public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
      System.out.println(parentPane.getScene()); // Prints null

      parentPane.sceneProperty().addListener((observable, oldScene, newScene) -> {
        if (newScene != null) {
          System.out.println(parentPane.getScene()); // Prints the Scene               
        }
      });
  }
}
```