# Run method in FXML Controller on KeyEvent

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have a function that updates a `ListView` in my FXML Controller Class. I want this to run every time the user presses `F5`.

I'm not sure what the best way is to achieve this and tried following:

#### 1. Get the scene from the controller

I tried to get the scene like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26061123/9820072) and added `scene.onKeyPressed(e -> ...);`. But I failed to find a way to get the scene reliably.

#### 2. Call the function from outside

Furthermore I tried to handle this from my scene controller, not my preferred way, because I don't want to call this method when this particular file is not loaded. I load the FXML file with `layout.setCenter(FXMLLoader.load(...));` I failed to get an instance of the Controller itself, where I could call the method.

What is wrong with my design? Or is there an @FXML annotation that allows me to handle a `KeyEvent`?

#### Example

ApplicationManager:

```java
@Override
public void start(Stage stage){
   BorderPane layout = new BorderPane();
   Scene scene = new Scene(layout);

   layout.setCenter(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/designs/lobby.fxml");
}
```

LobbyFxmlController:

```java
@FXML private ListView<Label> lobbyListView;

@FXML
public void initialize(){
    //I can't get the scene here
}

private void loadLobbies(){
    // I need to run this on F5 presses
    lobbyListView.setItems("lobby 1", "lobby 2", "lobby 3");
 }
```

Comment: [mcve] please .. and make sure you have worked through a tutorial on how to use fxml (each and every one comes with an explanation of how to attach event handlers ;)

Comment: On a Button I would add `onAction="#handlerMethod"` in the fxml file (and a corresponding method in the controller). But I want this on key presses in this view, what would be the correct action for this, and where would I put it?
Okay I answered my quastion there, sorry haha. I need to use `onKeyPressed` in the parent object in the FXML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to add `onKeyPressed="#handleKeyPress"` to the FXML layout item and handle this method in the Controller.