# JavaFX: callback called two times on KeyPressed event

Tags: java, javafx, scene

I've set a callback to the Scene onKeyPressed, but it gets called 2 times. In particular:

- if the **focus is on a TextField**, the method set onKeyPressed is **called 2 times**;
- if the focus is on a non-text-editable component (e.g. a Button), it gets called just once.

##### Debugging info

Breakpoint placed at line 181, the one that calls the `selectBack()` method.
From the debugger it appears that it's getting called always by that same event from Scene:

1. [first call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDPmt.png)
2. [second call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdvWu.png)

### Minimal Reproducible Example

I'm using Java11 (jdk-11.0.11) + JavaFX11 (javafx-sdk-11.0.2)

##### Project structure:

```
Test
|
+-src
   |
   +-application
   |         |
   |         +--Controller.java
   |         |
   |         +--Main.java
   |         |
   |         +--Test.fxml
   |
   module-info.java
```

##### Main.java class:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage){
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("Test.fxml"));
            AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            stage.setTitle("Test");
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
            
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

##### Controller.java class:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private AnchorPane base;
    private int counter = 0;

    public void initialize()
    {
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            this.base.getScene().setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
                if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE)
                    test(new ActionEvent());
            });
        });
        
    }
    
    @FXML private void move(ActionEvent event)
    {
    }
    
    @FXML private void test(ActionEvent event)
    {
        System.out.println("Counter: " + counter + " (" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ")");
        
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION, "Test");
        alert.setContentText("Counter: " + counter);
        alert.showAndWait();
        
        counter++;
    }
}
```

##### Test.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane id="base" fx:id="base" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="400.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/18" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.Controller">
   <children>
      <TextField layoutX="125.0" layoutY="187.0" />
      <Button layoutX="174.0" layoutY="273.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

##### module-info.java:

```
module test {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires transitive javafx.base;
    requires transitive javafx.graphics;
    
    opens application;
}
```

Run configuration with VM arguments: `--module-path "bin;C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib" -m test/application.Main`

To reproduce the issue: run the application and press 'ESC':

- if the focus is on the TextField, it will show the Alert 2 times;
- if the focus is on the Button, the Alert will show just once.

Comment: There is no need for `Platform.runLater()` here, but that is not the cause of the issue. Create and post a [mre] that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @James_D I've tried removing Platform.runLater() and it throws NullPointerException... however I cannot seem to reproduce that problem in a simplier project, I'll try to provide further details or to actually make that minimal reproducible example.

Comment: You would appear to have at least two handlers that will call `selectBack`, the one added to the scene and the one added via FXML. Could that be the problem? But as noted, I think a [mre] is necessary here.

Comment: What is null when you remove `Platform.runLater()`? Are you loading the FXML from a background thread? (Though that should actually be safe anyway.)

Comment: @James_D I'm loading it the same way I've found everywhere (from Main class, inside the start method got from Application class). However I had found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26061123/19544859), which explains why you shouldn't get the Scene from initialize() method

Comment: I think @Slaw is correct that you have multiple handlers. It looks like you have `selectBack` as callable from your FXML. Did you perhaps also set up a keybinding there somewhere? It would be useful if you show us the FXML (at least the parts that reference `selectBack`).

Comment: Ah, yes, I didn't notice the `getScene()`. That would cause a NPE, and `Platform.runLater()` doesn't necessarily *guarantee* to avoid it. It's better to register that handler at the point in the code where you create the `Scene` (perhaps in your application subclass). You can still call a method in the controller. But none of that is the cause of the problem; as suggested, post a [mre].

Comment: Do you have a button in the FXML with `cancelButton="true"` and `onAction="#selectBack"`?

Comment: @RuckusT-Boom I've updated the question with some links to the GitHub repository (with the interested classes).

Comment: Anyways, responding to @James_D , I'm still not able to reproduce the issue on another project, it seems not to happen there so I guess I'm missing something. However, in case I won't get to a fix, I'll just remove that key binding feature, since it's not strictly necessary.
Regarding the `cancelButton="true"` unfortunately I don't have anything like that

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the handler, run in debug mode, and examine the stack trace when you hit the breakpoint to see if you can determine where it's being called from.

Comment: @James_D I've edited the question again, adding the debug info, but I discovered something very weird: the problem occurs just when a TextField has the focus. I'm going to write a small minimal reproducible example and link it.

Comment: You have `onKeyTyped` handlers for your text fields. Does it still occur if you remove them? These are not a good idea anyway; to respond to changes in the text in a text field, you should register a listener with the text field's `textProperty`.  (Because, for example, if the user pastes text in using the mouse, your key handler won't be invoked and your UI will potentially be in an inconsistent state.)

Comment: Edit the question to include the [mre], don't link it.

Comment: Should I delete some part of the question to make it more clear or I can just append the Example at the end?

Comment: Assuming the [mre] reproduces the problem, I would delete large parts of the question. The [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73328208/revisions) is available anyway.

Comment: This doesn't reproduce the issue for me. I only see the alert once. JavaFX 18.0.1 on JDK 18.0.2.

Comment: @James_D is it possible that it was fixed between Java 11 and Java 18?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It seems like this is a misbehavior that has been fixed in OpenJFX 14.**

I can reproduce the behavior with OpenJFX 11.0.1 ... 13.0.2, but not with OpenJFX 14 and later!

The relevant issue in the OpenJDK bug tracker seems to be https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8092352 (RT-23952) , which caused the implementation of e.g. `com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent` to be changed.

**If you can, switching to OpenJFX 14+ is probably the best option.**

If you absolutely cannot update the JFX version:

- Consuming the event(s) does *not* help, as the two calls receive two different event instances.
- The only way I can think of to avoid triggering the dialog twice is to discard the second event if it comes too soon after the first one, which is a bit tricky because the second event is dispatched after the Alert is closed (because of the blocking `showAndWait` call), so we have to take that into account. There is the risk that we might discard "real" events, but because of the blocking Alert, it probably isn't much of a problem here.

Something like this:

```
public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private AnchorPane base;
    private int counter = 0;

    public void initialize() {
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            this.base.getScene().setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

                // might want to tweak this
                private final int DISCARD_EVENT_DISTANCE_MILLIS = 10;

                private Instant lastInteractionTimestamp = null;

                @Override
                public void handle(KeyEvent e) {
                    if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                        final Instant now = Instant.now();
                        System.out.println(now);
                        if (shouldDiscardEvent(now)) {
                            System.out.println("Discard event that comes too soon after previous interaction: " + now);
                            lastInteractionTimestamp = now;
                        } else {
                            lastInteractionTimestamp = test(new ActionEvent()); 
                        }
                    }
                }

                private boolean shouldDiscardEvent(final Instant now) {
                    return lastInteractionTimestamp != null
                            && lastInteractionTimestamp.plusMillis(DISCARD_EVENT_DISTANCE_MILLIS).isAfter(now);
                }
            });
        });

    }

    @FXML
    private void move(ActionEvent event) {
    }

    @FXML
    private Instant test(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Counter: " + counter + " (" + Instant.now() + ")");

        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION, "Test");
        alert.setContentText("Counter: " + counter);
        alert.showAndWait();

        counter++;
        return Instant.now();
    }
}
```